# How to get same height for all buttons?

Tags: jquery, css

These button made by `span` I want same height for all

[image]

How to get that? play with jsfiddle example here http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/Apz9e/16/

```
/* setting the width and height of the SELECT element to match the replacing graphics */
span.select, select.select {

width:auto ;
        height:auto ;
    font:3.2em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
   padding:7% 7%
}


select.select{
        position:relative;
        z-index:10;

        line-height:1;

}

select option {padding-top:3px; border-bottom:1px solid red}

/* dynamically created SPAN, placed below the SELECT */
span.select{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    float:left;
    left:2px;
    line-height:1;
    text-indent:10px
     background: #ffffff;
background: url('images/color-arrow.png') no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #a9a9a9 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#a9a9a9));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#a9a9a9 100%);
background: linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#a9a9a9 100%);
    cursor:default;
    z-index:1; 
    border:#dadada 1px solid; 
    border-radius:6px;    
    background-position: 100% center; 
    text-shadow:0px 1px 1px #fff; white-space:nowrap;
        diaplay:block
    }
```

Comment: Your span have different paddings, set padding to a fixed value instead of 7% in class "span.select, select.select" to test "padding:24px 24px"

Comment: @RaduMariș - see my comment on Savas's answer

Answer (score 3):

Apparently it's because you provided a percentage width for the padding in select. Basically, when you do so the padding will be set according to the width of the content. Say your width is `100px` then the padding will be `7px` in your case. Or when it is `1000px` it will be `70px`. Try to give a fixed padding to the `select.select` element instead of using percentage. That will solve your question.

Similarly, if you really going to use a percentage padding, then set a fixed width. It would work as well.

** EDIT **

The following is a simple workaround for your problem.

```
// on window resize
$(window).resize(function() { 
    var max = 0;
    // get the height of the longest select.select
    $("select.select").each(function() { 
       var h = $(this).height();
       if (h > max) 
          max = h;
    });
    // set the height of all select.select to max height
    $("select.select").height(h);
});
```

Comment: but because i'm using these buttons in a responsive website. button's width, height and fontsize increase and decrease upon re-sizing the browser/screen. so i gave `padding` in `%` to keep proportion

Comment: @JitendraVyas The problem is that you are not decreasing the font-size on browser-resize. If you're going to resize EVERYTHING, then you should also resize the font so that will seem more in proportinal. If you will decrease the font size then padding will not be equal but at least seem more proportional.

Comment: I'm also decreasing the font-size. in actual implementation. but the problem is not font-size as you can see in current example. font-size is same for all buttons but height is still unequal.

Comment: @JitendraVyas alright then the will seem proportionate. However they won't be equal because of the width. Anyways, you asked why, I answered why it is :) In my opinion, at least for select buttons, I'd go with fixed size. I'd prefer seeing 3 equal buttons than 3 different size buttons.

Comment: Ok i changed the title of question and now it's ok for me if there is any jquery solution

Comment: Thanks can you integrate in my jsfiddle example?

Comment: @JitendraVyas Check the link. http://jsfiddle.net/Apz9e/33/ . I removed the window resize function because I cannot resize that iframe.

Comment: The padding won't be equal unless you use a fixed padding or a fixed width. You may add a $(window).resize function when you integrate the code to your website.